# Calculate the hour plus one

Tags: java

Learning Java my current problem is with the "else" statement below. The result I am looking for is, if I type in 3 hours and 55 minutes: **"Five to Four"**

**With the code below I get:**
*Please enter the hours (between 1 and 12): 
3
Please enter the minutes (between 1 and 60): 
55
Five to Three*

Can someone please tell me what am I doing wrong? (Thanks)

```
// actual calcuations

    if(minuteValue==0){
        result = hourPart + minutePart + " o'clock"; // eg two o'clock (the String o'clock defined later in the minute values)
    }
    else if (minuteValue <= 30 ){
        result = minutePart + " past " + hourPart; // eg ten past five
    }
    else
    {
       int remainingtime = 60 - minuteValue;
       int nexthr = hourValue + 1;
       if(nexthr==13) nexthr = 1;  

       result = getHourString(remainingtime) + " to " + hourPart; // eg twenty to five

    }

    return result;
```

Comment: Add 1 to `hourPart` before concatenating.

Comment: show us the full code.  pretty sure `getHourString(int)` isnt a jdk function.

Comment: You have 3 different variables holding the hour: hourValue, hourPart and nexthr. I'm not sure what the difference between hourPart and hourValue is, but what's sure is that you initialize nexthr but never use it.

Comment: instead of `hourPart`, use `nexthr` while concatenating result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well first of all you're not using `nexthr`:

```
result = getHourString(remainingtime) + " to " + hourPart; //where's nexthr?
```

Secondly you got way to much stuff going on here. Just have `hourValue` and `minuteValue` to keep track of the entered time. Change `minutePart` to `minuteValue` and `hourPart` to `hourValue` and you're done:

```
String result;
int minuteValue = 55;
int hourValue = 9;

if(minuteValue==0){
    result = hourValue + minuteValue + " o'clock"; // eg two o'clock (the String o'clock defined later in the minute values)
}
else if (minuteValue <= 30 ){
    result = minuteValue + " past " + hourValue; // eg ten past five
}
else
{
   int remainingtime = 60 - minuteValue;
   int nexthr = hourValue + 1;
   if(nexthr==13) nexthr = 1;  
   result = remainingtime + " to " + nexthr; // eg twenty to five

}

System.out.println(result);
```

Result: `5 to 10`

Comment: Thank you Daniel Figueroa, I have made some progress!

Comment: **The desired result:**
*Please enter the hours (between 1 and 12): 
3
Please enter the minutes (between 1 and 60): 
45
Quater to Four*
**This is the code that fixed it for me:** 
   int remainingtime = 60 - minuteValue;
   int nexthr = hourValue + 1;
   if(nexthr==13) nexthr = 1;  
   result = getMinuteString(remainingtime) + " to " + getHourString(nexthr); // eg twenty to five
   // result = getHourString(remainingtime) + " to " + hourPart; // eg twenty to five

Answer (score 0):

```
String result;
int minuteValue = 55;
int hourValue = 9;

if(minuteValue==0){
    result = hourValue + minuteValue + " o'clock"; // eg two o'clock (the String o'clock defined later in the minute values)
}
else if (minuteValue <= 30 ){
    result = minuteValue + " past " + hourValue; // eg ten past five
}
else
{
   int remainingtime = 60 - minuteValue;
   int nexthr = hourValue + 1;
   if(nexthr==13) nexthr = 1;  
   result = remainingtime + " to " + nexthr; // eg twenty to five

}

System.out.println(result);
```